# Accessing specific key/values in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in object()">
  {{key}} : {{value}}
</ul>
```

Works great if I just want to spit out the whole object. I was wondering if there was a more handlebar/mustache way of passing an object and cherry picking only the ones that I want

```
{{#each}}
  {{this.Value1}} + {{this.Value6}}
{{/each}}
```

Hopefully I can do this without writing a directive? Or is that the best bet.

Comment: There are no keys in the second code block. Only values. Looks like you need `object.Value1` and `object.Value6`. Quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If object() looks like

```
{
   'key1': {
     'subkey1':'value1',
     'subkey2':'value2'
   },
   'key2': {
     'subkey1':'value3',
     'subkey2':'value4'
   }
}
```

and you want to just spit out subkey1 for each item in object

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in object()">
  <li>{{key}} : {{value.subkey1}}</li>
</ul>
```

and that would produce something like

```
<ul>
  <li>key1 : value1</li>
  <li>key2 : value3</li>
</ul>
```